# Convert time (24 hours format) in character type to time in R

Tags: r, datetime, strptime, chron

I have a data frame with time in character format, I need to convert it into time format. I have tried using strptime and POSIXct but it adds the date also. I just need the time.

For e.g.: `TRK_DEP_TIME <- c("22:00", "14:30"......)`  _____ character datatype

doing........ `as.POSIXCT(TRK_DEP_TIME, format = %H:%M")`

The result will be `("10/11/17,22:00", "10/11/17, 14:30".....)`

I am looking for just the time, I don't need the date to be associated with it. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use chron `"times"` class:

```
library(chron)

ch <- c("22:00", "14:30") # test input (character)
times(paste0(ch, ":00"))
## [1] 22:00:00 14:30:00
```